# Sort with different models' properties in Ember

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js

I understand that you can sort different properties in ascending/descending orders by doing the following:

```
App.TestsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
    sortProperties: ['testDate:desc', 'name:asc']
    sortedObjects: Ember.computed.sort('content', 'sortProperties')
)
```

and then referencing sortedObjects in {{#each}}. However, in the case that each test has a user associated with it, is there a way we can also sort by the user's properties? I've noticed that when I just sort by test properties or user properties, everything works fine, but when I do this:

```
App.TestsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
    sortProperties: ['testDate:desc', 'user.lastName:asc']
    sortedObjects: Ember.computed.sort('content', sortProperties')
)
```

I get an "Index out of range" error. Will I need to use my own sort to accommodate sorting through different models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what ended up being the issue was how I was setting up connections between tests and users. At first I was connecting users to tests in the setupController, which resulted in users being returned as promises to the controller. When I moved the process to the model hook, my loading screen was no longer showing up. If anyone runs into the same problem, I followed this [article](http://balinterdi.com/2014/01/21/promises-instead-of-callbacks.html) by Balint Erdi.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the object property to the controller:

```
App.TestsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
    needs: ['user'],
    lastName: '',
    lastNameBinding: 'controllers.user.lastName',
    sortProperties: ['testDate:desc', 'lastName:asc']
    sortedObjects: Ember.computed.sort('content', sortProperties')
)
```

You could also try a computed property.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out, Matthew! Your answer helped me get rid of the error, but it turns out that users were showing up as promises in my controller. For now I figured out a workaround where I explicitly set a user to each test, but do you have any idea why this might be happening?